# virtualization: your android phone userdata to an Android virtual device

Tags: android, virtual, android-virtual-device, qemu, user-data

Does anyone know how I can take the data from the userdata partition from a physical phone and transfer it into an Android Virtual Device(AVD) in such a way that the AVD can start up and look, more or less, just like it was on the orignal phone with apps and messages ect...?

I can copy out the userdata partition from a phone using adb and busybox and i have been playing around tranfering the userdata contents into the userdata-qemu.img of an Android virtual device in the hope the AVD would start up with all the apps and data more or less the way the user had it on their original phone. But so far the AVD won't start up after copying the data.

Any suggestions are welcome,
Thanks